# Is it possible to use pause/resume for copyTo in AIR?

Tags: air

Is it possible to use pause/resume for copyTo in AIR?
srcFile.copyToAsync(destFile, true);

Answer (score 0):

No. But you can write your own copy function that read from the source file and wrote to the destination file. That way you can implement your own pause/resume feature.